# Shuffle list of two teams facing each other in a league

Tags: java, algorithm, combinatorics

How would I go about shuffling a list of teams that face each other to never have them face each other twice?

I tried this. But looking at this it will only generate a matchup for team1 once. meaning team one will face the other teams once and all other teams each other twice (home, away). There are two problems with this.
1. The should only face each other once (to be able to repeat the number of rounds x times)
2. Team 1 will not get the same matchup as the other teams.

```
Example league
1-2
1-3 etc.

But team 2 will end up having this matchup (skipping team 1)
2-3
2-4 etc.

Team 3 will have
3-2 <---- Team 3 will here face team 2 again.
3-4 etc.
```

---

```
public List<Team[]> generateShuffledPairs(List<Team> teams) {
//Will add a dummy team if there are odd number of teams in the league      
listTeam = validateTeams(teams);
        int n = listTeam.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0 + 1; j < n; j++) {
                if (i != j)
                    listTeamPairs.add(new Team[] { listTeam.get(i), listTeam.get(j) });
            }
        }
        listTeamPairs.stream().forEach(p -> System.out.println(p[0].getName() + " - " + p[1].getName()));
        Collections.shuffle(listTeamPairs, new Random());
        listTeamPairs.stream().forEach(p -> System.out.println(p[0].getName() + " - " + p[1].getName()));
        return listTeamPairs;
    }
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a homework question, which does not include the required summary of the work done so far to solve the problem, nor a description of the difficulty encountered in solving it.

Comment: Homework? It's for a league where I make the homepage on my spare time.  I could of course brute force it but I am  wondering if there is an algorithm for solving this.

Comment: You can use [round robin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament), [single elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-elimination_tournament), or [double elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-elimination_tournament) scheduling.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific in the specification of this problem. If you just want to generate the (completed) list in the OP -- which is not shuffled -- then the solution is trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to generate all the pairs, and then shuffle them if you need them in random order.

```
public static List<int[]> generateShuffledPairs(int n) {
    ArrayList<int[]> pairs = new ArrayList<int[]>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= n; j++) {
            pairs.add(new int[] { i, j });
        }
    }

    Collections.shuffle(pairs, new Random());
    return pairs;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int[] pair : generateShuffledPairs(10)) {
        System.out.println("" + pair[0] + "-" + pair[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually this solution will generate a match where the team face itself which is incorrect. However it will shuffle. so adding below "// paring: i <> j" will make the solution complete.

Comment: Stupid misstake in my code. for (int j = 0 + 1; j < n; j++) { shouold be int j = i + 1

Comment: I dont see how this could generate pairs with repeating items.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < teams.length; ++i)
{
    for(int j = i + 1; j < teams.length; ++j)
    {
        // paring: i <> j
    }
}
```